# ¿Cómo navego por los anteriores comandos en IPython?

Tags: python, macos, ipython

Estoy usando IPython para ejecutar unos comandos. Funciona bien, todo es fantástico, hasta que quiero volver a ejecutar un comando anterior y el historial está lleno de comandos de muchas líneas: en ese momento toca subir línea a línea cada comando hasta saltar al anterior y así sucesivamente. Por tanto, si quiero subir al comando que ejecuté hace dos "intros" y el inmediatamente anterior tiene 20 líneas, debo subir una a una esas 20 líneas.

Veo que podría usar <kbd>PageUp</kbd> pero estoy trabajando en un MacBook y cuando lo hago me navega por la ventana, no por el historial de comandos.

¿Cómo puedo saltar al comentario anterior o posterior al actual en IPython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Linux o similares, puedes usar <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd> para navegar por los comandos.

---

En Macbook, puedes usar:

- <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> para ir al anterior comando
- <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> para ir al siguiente